# How to pass boots args to a Hyper-V VM

Tags: hyper-v

I need to add some extra key=value pairs in the /proc/cmdline file of my Linux VM.

On a XenServer hypervisor, I can use XenAPI call[`VM.set_PV_args`](http://downloads.xen.org/Wiki/XenAPI/xenapi-1.0.6.pdf)

What is the equivalent in Hyper-V 2012?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK the only way to do this with Hyper-V is to mount the vhd and edit the file.
or, use a virtual floppy (which I don't think will have any effect in your case).  This can be done through wmi.

Hyper-V does not have an equivalent to the PV vm of xenserver. Where many of these xenserver pv arguments are simple configuration of a boot file in the settings of the vm, as the vm gets boot strapped from the parent kernel.

if you could do this with a xenserver HVM style Linux vm, then there might be a similar equivalent in Hyper-V.

Comment: I'm using set_PV_args() to feed runtime data into the read only file /proc/cmdline.  For Hyper-V, I'll use the "KVP" component instead.